# MySQL query to return a value if valus in two different rows match a condition

Tags: mysql

In the example below, I'm trying to create a query that returns the content of `NAME` if this contains both **'ammonium nitrate'** and **'urea'**. The thing is, they are in separate rows and I haven't found how to check for both. I've tried using the clauses `IN`, `AND`, and `UNION`, but to no avail.

The query should return only **'Gro-Fast'**, as it is the only `NAME` that contains both.

```
+-------+------------------+-------------+---------+
| FCODE | CNAME            | NAME        | CONTACT |
+-------+------------------+-------------+---------+  
| 28994 | ammonium nitrate | Gro-Fast    |  556698 |  
| 28994 | urea             | Gro-Fast    |  556698 |  
| 29462 | ammonium nitrate | BetterRoots |  342554 |  
| 34588 | ammonium nitrate | Flourisher  |  342554 |  
| 83732 | urea             | GreenAgain  |  354211 |  
+-------+------------------+-------------+---------+
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by name` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select name
from tablename
where cname in ('ammonium nitrate', 'urea')
group by name
having count(distinct cname) = 2
```

If you want the column `cname`to contain **only** 'ammonium nitrate' and 'urea':

```
select name
from tablename
group by name
having 
  sum(cname not in ('ammonium nitrate', 'urea')) = 0
  and
  count(distinct cname) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d39f2e5993a5b98fd7672cecf1908b01).
Results:

```
> | name     |
> | :------- |
> | Gro-Fast |
```

Edit, for your query:

```
select name
from CONTENTS natural join FERTILIZERS
where cname in ('ammonium nitrate', 'urea')
group by name
having count(distinct cname) = 2
```

Comment: to get the table above I used
`SELECT   
*  
FROM  
CONTENTS  
NATURAL JOIN  
FERTILIZERS  
WHERE  
CNAME IN ('ammonium nitrate' , 'urea');`